# Caching Behavior in JAX

Tags: python, jit, jax

I have a function `f` that takes in a boolean static argument `flag` and performs some computation based on it's value. Below is a rough outline of this function.

```py
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['flag'])
def f(x, flag):
   # Preprocessing
   if flag:
      ...
   else:
      ...
   # Postprocessing
```

Each time `f` is called with a different value of `flag`, a recompilation of this function should be triggered. However, because `flag` is a boolean and can take on at most two values, it would be preferable if JAX would cache the compiled version of `f` for each of the possible values of `flag` and avoid recompilations.

In short, I would like JAX to compile `f` only two times when running following piece of code:

```py
flag = True
for i in range(100):
   f(x, flag)
   flag = not flag
```

Is there a way to tell JAX not to throw away old compiled versions of `f`, each time it's called with a new value of `flag`? And in general, are there any caching mechanisms implemented in JAX for such scenarios? (For instance if `flag` is an integer, but we know beforehand that it would only ever take `k` distinct values, and we would like to save the compiled version of `f` for each of these `k` values)

I know that I can use `jax.lax.cond` or `jax.lax.switch` to control the flow inside `f` and treat `flag` as a regular argument rather than a static one. But this would make the code much more bloated (and difficult to read) as there are several places within the body of `f` where I access `flag`. It would be much cleaner if I declared `flag` to be a static argument and then controled the caching behavior of `jax.jit` to avoid recompilations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then JAX by default behaves the way you would like it to behave. Each JIT-compiled function has an LRU cache of compilations based on the `shape` and `dtype` of dynamic arguments and the hash of static arguments. You can inspect the size of this cache using the `_cache_size` method of the compiled function. For example:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnames=['flag'])
def f(x, flag):
   if flag:
       return jnp.sin(x)
   else:
       return jnp.cos(x)

print(f._cache_size())
# 0

x = jnp.arange(10)
f(x, True)
print(f._cache_size())
# 1

f(x, False)
print(f._cache_size())
# 2

# Subsequent calls with the same flag value hit the cache:
flag = True
for i in range(100):
    f(x, flag)
    flag = not flag
print(f._cache_size())
# 2
```

Since the size of the `x` argument hasn't changed, we get one cache entry for each value of `flag`, and the cached compilations are used in subsequent calls.

Note however if you change the `shape` or `dtype` of the dynamic argument, you get new cache entries:

```py
x = jnp.arange(100)
for i in range(100):
    f(x, flag)
    flag = not flag
print(f._cache_size())
# 4
```

The reason this is necessary is that, in general, functions may change its behavior based on these static quantities.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Just as a follow up, are there any limits on the maximum size of `_cache_size()`?

Comment: The max cache size for each jit-compiled function is [4096](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4139a2ada21479f923a850bf2708dfe077a22254/tensorflow/compiler/xla/python/pjit.cc#L81) after which the least recently used compilation result is discarded