# Jax scan with dynamic number of iterations

Tags: python-3.x, jax

I wanted to perform a [scan](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html) with a dynamic number of iterations. To accomplish that, I want to recompile the function each time when `iters_to_do` changes.

To avoid a huge slowdown, I'll be using a [`recompilation_cache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75641884/caching-behavior-in-jax) but that's beside the point.

However, when I mark the argument in `@partial(jax.jit)` I'm still obtaining a concretization error:

```py
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(3))
def iterate_for_steps(self,
                        interim_thought: Array, 
                        mask: Array,
                        iters_to_do: int, 
                        input_arr: Array, 
                        key: PRNGKeyArray) -> Array:

    # These are constants
    input_arr = input_arr.astype(jnp.bfloat16)
    interim_thought = interim_thought.astype(jnp.bfloat16)
    
    def body_fun(i: int, thought: Array) -> Array:
        latent = jnp.concatenate([thought, input_arr], axis=-1).astype(jnp.bfloat16)
        latent = self.main_block(latent, input_arr, mask, key).astype(jnp.bfloat16)
        latent = jax.vmap(self.post_ln)(latent).astype(jnp.bfloat16)  # LN to keep scales tidy

        return latent
    
    iters_to_do = iters_to_do.astype(int).item()
    final_val = jax.lax.scan(body_fun, interim_thought, xs=None, length=iters_to_do)
    
    return final_val
```

##### Full traceback is [here](https://rentry.co/dc9wgq24).

I've tried marking multiple arguments with `@partial` but to no avail.

I'm not sure how to approach debugging this - with a python debugger, I'm getting no help apart from the fact that its definitely a tracer.

### MRE

```py
from functools import partial
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

init = jnp.ones((5,))
iterations = jnp.array([1, 2, 3])

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(0,))
def iterate_for_steps(iters: int):
    def body_fun(carry):
        return carry * 2
    
    iters = iters.astype(int)
    output = jax.lax.scan(body_fun, init, xs=None, length=iters)
    
    return output

print(jax.vmap(iterate_for_steps)(iterations))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use equinox's (internal as of right now) [`while_loop`](https://github.com/patrick-kidger/equinox/blob/1e601672d38d2c4d483535070a3572d8e8508a20/equinox/internal/_loop/loop.py#L22) implementation which would also be able to handle a dynamic amount of iterations with checkpointing to reduce memory usage.

Note that this can be used as a drop-in replacement to jax's native `while_loop`. One can also use equinox's `eqx.internal.scan` if they wish to leverage similar checkpointing with `scan`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the number of iterations in a `scan` must be static. If you want something similar to scan that allows a dynamic number of iterations, you can take a look at [`while_loop`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.while_loop.html).

Regarding your code: in isolation, your fix of marking `iters_to_do` as static using `static_argnums` is probably roughly the right idea, so long as you are passing a static `int` in this position when you call the function.

But the fact that you are calling the `astype` array method in your function (in `iters_to_do.astype(int).item()`) and getting a `ConcretizationError` rather than an `AttributeError` makes me think that the error you linked to is not coming from the code as pasted in your question.

To help address this discrepancy, I'd suggest trying to construct a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you're having. Without that, any answer to your question is going to require too much guesswork regarding what code you're actually executing.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the quick respose! MRE added :)

Comment: Any argument passed via `vmap` is dynamic, and there is no way to make it static. You won't be able to use `scan` in this context. I'd suggest looking into `while_loop`.

Comment: I was using equinox's `while_loop` but I found it a bit slow, because it adds unecessary dynamicness. Still, thanks so much!

Comment: One alternative may be to not vmap over a scan, but rather scan over a vmap, where the (static) scan size is the maximum of the iterations across batches.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you tbh